# Duplicate GUI with a Button

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to code a Button to reopen/duplicate my user interface.
My programm is a calculation tool, the goal is just to reopen exactly the same tool, such that two identical tools are open and calculations can be done simultanious.

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Calculation tool')
tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root)

tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)

tabControl.add(tab1, text='Tab1')
tabControl.add(tab2, text='Tab2')
tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

def openNewWindow():
     newWindow = Toplevel(root)

duplicate = Button(tab3, text='Duplicate', command=openNewWindow)
duplicate.place(x=20, y=20)
```

Comment: Do you want to start a new process? Or do you want to open a new window in the current process?

Comment: I guess a new process is better? I don't really know what the advantages or consequences are of new, or current process.

Comment: New process will be what you want since heavy calculations will block up the thread if you run both on the same process. Is there any reason you can't just use `subprocess` to launch a copy of the current file?

Comment: I have just no idea how to do it. That's the only reason why I am asking.

Comment: You could create your own GUI class that creates and runs in its own `Toplevel` instance (or is derived from that class). This way you could create a many instances as you wished. There is no built-in generic way to duplicate the contents of an existing `Tk` or `Toplevel` instance.